# What mind of plants like Ash Fertilizer/ an npk of 0:2:13?

Tags: fertilizer

My wife has aquired some kittens and is using pellet fuel for their litter box. I believe she gos through about 7kg's a week.

When looking at it, I see its also described as Ash Fertilizer and even has NPK values on it 0:2.3:13.4

Rather then throwing this (Urea enriched!) fertilizer into the trash, it seems it could be useful in my garden.

Any ideas what trees and plants like it?  (Among others I have Citrus trees, Feijoas and Stone Fruit - but I can keep a lookout for other trees - especially ones producing edibles that grow in Hardiness Zone 9/10 as well)

Answer (score 1):

After spending time in the litter box, it will no longer be 0 on the N front...

Since you plan to use it on edibles, stock advice (and regulations in most areas with regulations) for all raw animal manures is that they should not be applied within 120 days of harvest.

If you are going to use it at all, it should be composted first. Since it is specifically cat waste, it should be hot-composted (which most home compost piles are exceedingly dubious at) or otherwise heat-treated if it is to be used at all, or the risk of [toxoplasmosis](https://www.cdc.gov/parasites/toxoplasmosis/biology.html) is rather extreme.